# Display/Access the Windows Certificate Viewer via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, certificate, x509certificate, pki

I've found a question or two regarding accessing the built-in Windows Certificate viewer using a .NET framework.

I'm wondering, however, if there's a way to display a certificate's information using the Windows Certificate viewer via JavaScript. I have a page on which a user can drop/upload a local file, and then the JavaScript code extracts the certificate information stored in this file. I would love to be able to pump that directly into the Windows Certificate viewer to give the user a familiar interface to work with.

Is this possible with plain 'ol JavaScript? I don't have access to many non-standard libraries.

The page doesn't need to store anything or upload any information anywhere; it is simply supposed to give information about the given file and its contained certificate data.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor, no there is no access to the local certificate store from Javascript. This would be a violation of the browsers same-origin security policy.

Your only choice to do this would be to use a Java applet, browser plug-in or COM control to escape the sandbox.

Depending on what you want to do it might be viable to stay in the sandbox and use something like https://pkijs.org.

Otherwise I think your out of luck.